# Short story: intelligent dogs create androids

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story I'm looking for takes place in the far future. Humans have long since left for space. The Earth is dominated by intelligent dogs and cats, who are in conflict with each other. The dogs, who were domesticated for far longer than cats, miss humanity and create androids to take their place. A contributor recalled the detail that at the end, the dogs look up into the eyes of their creations and are pleased that they now have masters again.

It is not [City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_(novel)) by Clifford Simak. I am guessing it was written in the '80s.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the Pemalites from Animorphs.

Comment: I remember this story.  At the end the dogs look up into they eyes of their creations and are pleased that they now have masters again.  No idea as to title or author but adding that piece of data in hopes that it will jog someone else's memory.

Comment: Yes, that is it exactly Emsley. I so wish I could find it!